# Error deleting Managed Account

Tags: sharepoint-server, managed-account

SharePoint 2010 Server. When I try and delete this account I get this error.

```
The account DOMAIN\sp_Services is still being used by these components: 
Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Tracing.
```

Where on earth is Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Tracing? It's not a Service and it's not a Service application and it's not listed in the Services where you set the managed accounts.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this on the server

`Start > administrator Tools > Services`, Now check the SharePoint Tracing Service, Under which account this is running? You should check this on all server in farm. If the account is being used here then change it.

Also try to powershell:

```
$account = Get-SPManagedAccount -identity "domain\login"
Remove-SPManagedAccount $account
```

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff607697.aspx

Comment: There are no services using that account. I switched them all and rebooted several times. Attempting to delete the Managed account via the UI or PowerShell states that the account is used by the Microsoft SharePoint Foundation Tracing service.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the following powershell code:

```
$svc = (Get-SPFarm).Services | ? {$_.Name -eq "SPTraceV4"}

# Get the managed account from SharePoint
$svcIdentity = Get-SPManagedAccount $AccountName

# Set the tracing service to run under the managed account. $svc.ProcessIdentity.CurrentIdentityType = "SpecificUser"
$svc.ProcessIdentity.ManagedAccount = $svcIdentity
$svc.ProcessIdentity.Update()
```