# The account "username1" is still being used by these components: SharePoint Server Search

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, 2010, managed-account

similar to the question,i have found here 
[Error deleting Managed Account](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/173837/error-deleting-managed-account)

am using SharePoint 2010 Server and when I try and delete this account I get this error.

> The account DOMAIN\muser1 is still being used by these components: 
>   SharePoint Server Search.

What am i doing wrong ? 
i tried to delete this using powershell, but that also thrown into error.

```
$account = Get-SPManagedAccount -identity "domain\muser1"
Remove-SPManagedAccount $account
```

and when i tried to select the newly created special id account for the sp search in "configure service accounts link in central admin" , after selecting the `search` dropdown item and clicking ok, am getting the below error

> 'mapAccountPicker' has a SelectedValue which is invalid because it does not exist in the list of items. 
>   Parameter name: value

Troubleshoot issues with Microsoft SharePoint Foundation.

Correlation ID: 642976cd-5cbe-4f66-8d3f-be5aa76d6853

Date and Time: 10/16/2017 5:24:51 P

Answer (score 1):

You are unable to delete a managed account which is used in a service.

To solve this issue, create a new user and register a managed account using this new user, then go to Configure Service accounts, configure all services which is used the old managed account to use the new managed account.